# Use any version as bower/npm dependency

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm, bower

I have a bower package of the library that depend on jQuery and latest version of my library have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2"
}
```

is it possible to use

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "any"
}
```

or

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "*"
}
```

so it use any version that's fit for other dependencies.

I can't seems to find any documentation about it, is it possible to do the same in npm?

**EDIT**: mainly I need version ~3 or ~2 if other dependencies require version 2 because of [XSS and DOS Vulnerabilities that was found in my library](https://snyk.io.cnpmjs.org/test/npm/jquery.terminal) because of old jQuery.

Comment: Interesting question... I suspect it isn't possible because, after all, you'd be lying. You haven't tested your code in ancient versions of jQuery and you cannot assure that all future jQuery releases ever will be backwards compatible ad infinitum.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález mainly I want to fix this issue I've found https://snyk.io.cnpmjs.org/test/npm/jquery.terminal because of jQuery version 2.2.4 and I want it to grab version ~3 but I also want it to grab version ~2 if other packages need version ~2.